# OSGi external sqlite jar

Tags: java, jar, osgi, bundle

I am having a problem to include an external jar at OSGi. I have tried various ways but there is not success.

- Tried to include as a library at java build path at my bundle.
- Tried to include as Bundle-ClassPath: .,my3rdparty.jar
- Also tried to with build.gradle but there is not luck.

My code:

```
private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{
  // sqlite driver
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  // database path, if it's new database, it will be created in the project folder
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:SQLiteTest1.db");
  initialise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download sqlite jar(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.21.0.1) that is osgi compatible.
Deploy the sqlite jar.
Edit your MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF folder and enter the imported packages under Import-Package field.
Deploy your application bundle.

Comment: I don't have any folder META-INF. I have tried with lib folder but got the same error.

Comment: Which osgi platform you are using? I think bundle should have META-INF folder.